# How to resolve 404 error when making an image uploaded with reactjs and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to set up an image uploader for my web app. I'm using node.js for the backend and react.js for the front end with mongodb as well. The problem is I'm getting a 404 ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED whenever I try to upload the image.

I've tried a few things like changing the router name for the axios.post in react to no avail. I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

What I think is the relevant code is here:

react (upload-page.js):

```
fileUploadHandler = () => {
    const fd = new FormData(); 
    fd.append('photo', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name); 
    axios.post('http://localhost8080/api/images', fd, {
      onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
        console.log('Upload Progress:' + Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total* 100) + '%')
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res); 
      });
    }
```

server.js:

```
app.use('/api/users/', usersRouter);
app.use('/api/auth/', authRouter);
app.use('/api/images/', uploadRouter);
```

router.js:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images', storage: multer.memoryStorage() });
const Image = require('./models');

const router = express.Router(); 

//app.use(express.static('public'));

router.post('/', upload.single('imageField'), (req, res) => {
    if(req.file) {
        console.error(req.file);
        const i = new Image({
            data: req.file.buffer
        });
        i.save().then(() => {
            return res.status(201).json({
                id: i._id
            });
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'error: ' + e.message})
        });
    }
    else {
        throw 'error';
    }
});

module.exports = router ;
```

Full code can be found at these repos: 
Backend: https://github.com/beccaww/cats
Frontend: https://github.com/beccaww/cats-client

I expect it to upload the image into the /images/uploads/images on the backend but it just gives me a 404 ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED message instead. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Edit:

Okay, I fixed the `axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/images', fd, {`, but now I'm getting a 500 error that says: POST http://localhost:8080/api/images 500 (Internal Server Error), followed by: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Is the error in your browser, or in the terminal where your server is running? One thing is that your POST call is pointing to `'http://localhost8080/api/images'`, I think you want `'http://localhost:8080/api/images'` (colon between `localhost` and the port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a colon between `localhost` and the port (Should be `localhost:8080`, not `localhost8080`)

Comment: Thanks, that did get rid of the 404, but now I have a 500 error. Any idea why?

Comment: What's the error? 500 error means something went wrong on the server, so it's likely hitting the endpoint but something's going wrong in the `post` handler.

Comment: It says: POST http://localhost:8080/api/images 500 (Internal Server Error), followed by: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: It sounds like an error in the `post` route you have in your description. You should be seeing error logs in your console where you're running the server, those might give you a better idea of what's going wrong. If not, put some more logs in until you narrow down the problem. The client-side error won't be uncaught if you add a `.catch` after the `axios.post(...).then(...)`

Comment: Thank you, it was in the ```post``` route. I had the ```fd.append{'photo'``` when it should have been ```fd.append{'imageField'```. It works fine now.

Comment: Good! Glad I could help!